# Bullet Points are not Visible

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I recently made a small script for school to organize, create, and format a beginner Google Apps Script for Google Slides. The script shows no errors when executing, however when I go to the Slideshow to look at what I accomplished, only the titles of each slide are visible. All other body texts and bullet points are not visible, yet they register in the script. Please help!

Here is the code, it is not optimized as it is just a draft.

```
function createPresentation() {
  var title = "The Importance of Budgeting";
  var slides = [    {      title: "Introduction",      bullets: [        "What is budgeting?",        "Why is budgeting important?",        "How can budgeting help you achieve your financial goals?"      ],
      colors: ["#cfe2f3", "#fafafa"]
    },
    {
      title: "Track Your Income and Expenses",
      bullets: [
        "Why is tracking your income and expenses important?",
        "How can you track your income and expenses?",
        "What tools can help you with tracking your income and expenses?"
      ],
      colors: ["#fce5cd", "#fafafa"]
    },
    {
      title: "Create a Budget",
      bullets: [
        "What is a budget?",
        "Why is creating a budget important?",
        "How can you create a budget?",
        "What are some tips for creating an effective budget?"
      ],
      colors: ["#d9ead3", "#fafafa"]
    },
    {
      title: "Stick to Your Budget",
      bullets: [
        "Why is sticking to your budget important?",
        "How can you stick to your budget?",
        "What are some common budgeting pitfalls to avoid?"
      ],
      colors: ["#f4cccc", "#fafafa"]
    },
    {
      title: "Conclusion",
      bullets: [
        "Budgeting can help you take control of your finances.",
        "By tracking your income and expenses and creating a budget, you can achieve your financial goals.",
        "Stick to your budget and make adjustments as needed to ensure long-term success."
      ],
      colors: ["#d9d2e9", "#fafafa"]
    }
  ];
  
  var presentation = SlidesApp.create(title);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var slide = presentation.appendSlide();
    slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.RECTANGLE, 0, 0, 500, 500).getFill().setSolidFill(slides[i].colors[0]);
    slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.RECTANGLE, 400, 0, 100, 500).getFill().setSolidFill(slides[i].colors[1]);
    var titleBox = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 10, 10, 380, 80);
    titleBox.getText().setText(slides[i].title);
    titleBox.getText().getTextStyle().setBold(true).setFontSize(42).setFontFamily("Calibri");
    
    for (var j = 0; j < slides[i].bullets.length; j++) {
      var bullet = slides[i].bullets[j];
      if (slide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.BODY) !== null) {
        var textRange = slide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.BODY).asShape().getText();
        textRange.appendListItem(bullet).getTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setFontFamily("Calibri");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried looking online for help but to no avail. Stack Overflow is my last resort LOL.

Comment: Can you provide your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (slide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.BODY) !== null) {
var textRange = slide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.BODY).asShape().getText();
textRange.appendListItem(bullet).getTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setFontFamily("Calibri");}
```